# Heap (HeapAlloc) Corruption in release mode only

Tags: c++, multithreading

Heap (HeapAlloc) Corruption in release mode only

Comment: If on Linux use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/); and your question is OS & implementation specific.

Comment: its on windows..sorry i missed it question..

Comment: You have possible memory leaks in your program. If `CreateMutex` fails, you don't free the data you have allocated.

Comment: thanks Joachim, i will correct that part,

Comment: Also, what is `WorkerThreadInfo_T`? I assume it's a POD-type with no constructor? And from where do you call `cleanup`? Is it called from the `jobCE` destructor (if you have any)? Do you anywhere copy the `jobCE` objects, making you possibly need to do a deep copy?

Comment: Hi Joachim, I have added WorkerThreadInfo_T, it is a structure. cleanup is called from main thread once it gets the callback of jobcompletion.

main thread keeps the instance of JobCE,

Answer (score 1):

I can just guess but why wouldn't you check the result of HeapFree? Because according the documentation it could be the reason. Try to use HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE flag when you allocate heap.

> You should not refer in any way to memory that has been freed by HeapFree. After that memory is freed, any information that may have been in it is gone forever. If you require information, do not free memory containing the information. Function calls that return information about memory (such as HeapSize) may not be used with freed memory, as they may return bogus data. Calling HeapFree twice with the same pointer can cause heap corruption, resulting in subsequent calls to HeapAlloc returning the same pointer twice.
>
> Serialization ensures mutual exclusion when two or more threads attempt to simultaneously allocate or free blocks from the same heap. There is a small performance cost to serialization, but it must be used whenever multiple threads allocate and free memory from the same heap. Setting the HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE value eliminates mutual exclusion on the heap. Without serialization, two or more threads that use the same heap handle might attempt to allocate or free memory simultaneously, likely causing corruption in the heap. The HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE value can, therefore, be safely used only in the following situations:
>
> ```
> The process has only one thread.
> The process has multiple threads, but only one thread calls the heap functions for a specific heap.
> The process has multiple threads, and the application provides its own mechanism for mutual exclusion to a specific heap.
> ```

Comment: but here in my process, there are multiple thread and all are being allocated memory from process heap.

Comment: ok, it is another story. If your WorkerThread can also allocate or free heap don't use HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE flag otherwise you have to provide you own synchronization. Try to check what HeapFree returns. > Return value
> If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
> If the function fails, the return value is zero. An application can call GetLastError for extended error <br />

Comment: no, worker thread cant allocate heap memory, it is the main thread which will allocate memory from heap for worker thread...